# Addressing DatagridView Datasource from another object trigger event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I am programming an interactive datagridview on WPF, the user can click on cells causing the content to change via selecting from multiple data sources. When the user click a cell the double click cell event is triggered like:

```
private TabItem item(..){

Table= new forms.DataGridView();
Table.DataSource = DataSource1(); //Default
Table.CellDoubleClick += delegate (object sender, forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs args){

{
var senderGrid = (forms.DataGridView)sender;

//Depending on some conditions the user can switch to DataSource2(), DataSource3() 
if(Condition 1)
senderGrid.DataSource = DataSource2();

}
```

Up until this point, everything works as intended ! The table double click event switches data sources as programmed.

Now the issue occurs, when I want to update the table from a Combo Box event trigger. The table remains simply unchanged, I guess I am not addressing the object correctly.

```
//Still inside the same TabItem item(..)
newCombo.DropDownClosed += delegate (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
if(Condition)
 Table.DataSource = DataSource2();  
}
```

Is there a way to control the table outside its event functions ?

Comment: Isn't this winforms and a winforms datagridview rather than wpf?

Comment: This is WPF, but the functionality is written in the code behind and XAML is not used at all !!

Comment: @ShortCircuit: `Table` is apparently not the same as the `DataGridView` that triggers the working event handler then. What does `senderGrid == Table` return?

Comment: it returns the object that triggered the event  (in this case Table) and Table is an object of type DataGridView.

Comment: @Andy I see what you mean. Yes this is winforms datagridview not the WPF Datagrid.

Comment: As until now I have found a workaround but it is far from clean. I do invoke datagridview.MultiSelectChanged(..) whenever I want to change the data source.